# Regex for iOS Bundle ID in platform for application registered in Azure B2C

Tags: ios, regex, azure-ad-b2c, regex-lookarounds

I need a regex with max 222 chars

- must use a-z A-Z 0-9
- can also have . and -
  but:
- can not start from . or -
- can not end with . or -
- can not have multiple like ".." or "--"
- can not have only . or -

Examples:

**GOOD**:

*asd.asd.asd.asd.asd.aadas.asdasdasd*

*as-d.asd.a-sd*

**BAD**:

*.asd.asd*

*-asd.-asd*

*.-asd.asd*

*asd.asd.*

*asd.asd-*

*asd.asd.-*

*asd.asd-.*

*asd.asd--*

*asd..*

*asd.asd-.asd*

*.-*

*asd--asd..asd*

I ended up with something like this
`^[^-.]((?!--)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]\.?[^-]){1,100}[^-.]$`
but it does not cover this case like `asd.asd-.asd`

**this is regex for platform iOS Bundle ID in app registration**. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might write it without the hyphen in the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]`

(Note that if the `-` is at the start or end, you don't have to escape it)

```
^(?=.{1,100}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.{1,100}$)` Assert 1-100 chars
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Repeat 1+ times matching any of the listed
- `(?:[-.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat either `-` or `.` and repeat 1+ times any of the listed
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kw8hq4/1)

Comment: do we really need 'not capturing group'  ```?:``` if yes why don't we have it in first part of this regex too?

Comment: @freak_geek The first part of the pattern is a match `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` which does not have to be in a group because we are not doing anything with the group itself. This part of the pattern `(?:[-.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` is grouped to repeat as a whole. You can turn the non capture group into a capture group `([-.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` but for a match only, you don't need the group value it self.